# Duplicating an image file (.bmp) to a different location

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing

I am a newbie in OpenCV programming using VS2010

and would like to copy an image file from where it is

created by a program into another directory. Here is the situation:

The program that I have taken over has the following snippet:

```
IplImage * I = cvQueryFrame( camera );

char * outFileName = new char[ 50 ];

strcpy( outFileName, "Image.bmp" );

if( !cvSaveImage( outFileName, I ) )
     printf( "Could not save: %s\n", outFileName );
```

Now, I would like to duplicate this image onto another directory. So, I wrote:

```
FILE * outFileName;
FILE * duplImage;

int i = 0; 

outFileName = fopen( "Image.bmp", "r" );

inFileName = fopen( duplImage, "w" );

while (???) 
{ 
???;
i++;
}

fclose( outFileName ); 
fclose( inFileName );
```

What do I do in the **???** bits?

Is there an OpenCV command that copies `C://blahblah/Image.bmp` onto `D://blahblah/duplImage.bmp` ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cvLoadImage function for read image from file to memory, then use cvSaveImage to write image to another file. But if you use **C++**, it is better to use imread and imwrite. See ["Load, Modify, and Save an Image"](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html) in OpenCV tutorial.

If you want only copy file with image, you can use OS specific function (CopyFile for Windows OS) or [boost filesystem::copy_file().](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_file)